# validation with regex javascript space and - sign does not used at the start or end of charcter

Tags: javascript

I am building a form and validate it with regex in javascript I have tried many this in regex but not working.

```js
//Empty field check function
    
 function Emptyfield(fld)
 {
  var error = "";
  if(fld.value.length == 0)
  {
   fld.style.background = "Yellow";
   error = "input field must not be empty.\n";
  }
  else 
  {
   fld.style.background = "white";
  }
  return error;

 }

    //username validation function

    function validateusername(fld) {
    var error = "";
    var illegalChar =  /^[^-\s][\w]+$/;
 
    if (fld.value == "") {
        fld.style.background = 'Yellow'; 
        error = "username field is required.\n";
    } 
 else if (illegalChar.test(fld.value)) {
        fld.style.background = 'Yellow'; 
        error = "Username contains illegal Characters.\n";
    } else {
        fld.style.background = 'White';
    }
    return error;}

    // Calling all functions Here
    
    function CheckForm(theForm) {
    var reason = "";
    
      reason += validateusername(theForm.username);
      /*reason += validateEmail(theForm.pwd);
      reason += validateEmail(theForm.email);
      reason += validatePhone(theForm.phone);
      reason += validateEmpty(theForm.from);/**/
          
      if (reason != "") {
         alert("Some fields need correction:\n" + reason);
        return false;
      }
    
      return true;
    }
```

```html
 <form name="demo" onsubmit="return CheckForm(this)">
   <ul>  
    <li> <label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" name="username" size="30" class="field" id="username"></li>  
    <li> <label for="email">   Email</label>   <input type="text" name="email"    size="30" class="field" id="email"></li>
    <li> <label for="phone">  Phone No.</label><input type="text" name="phone"    size="30" class="field" id="phone"></li>
    <li> <label for="date">   Date     </label><input type="text" name="date"     size="30" class="field" id="date"></li>
    <li> <label for="comment">Comments </label><textarea type="text" name="comment" rows="5" cols="32" class="field" id="comment-box"></textarea></li>
   </ul>
             <input type="submit" value = "submit" id="submit-btn">
     </form>
```

in the last function, I am calling all function that is on top.

Comment: Can you share the rules of a valid `username`?

Comment: i do not want space and - (hyphen) sign to be used at the start and end of the username

Comment: remove/ comment out this line of code form you last one function reason += validateEmail(theForm.pwd);

Comment: @MuhammadRoman Did it worked?

Answer (score 0):

> i do not want space and - (hyphen) sign to be used at the start and
>   end of the username

You can try

```
var illegalChars = [ " ", "-" ];
var isValidInput = illegalChars.indexOf( fld.value.charAt(0) ) != 1;
```